# Contrib.Cache version compatibility

Tags: orchardcms

I tried to install the `Contrib.Cache` module to my Orchard 1.3.9 setup but it caused various compilation errors. Is this module only supported by more advanced versions of Orchard?

Comment: For the user that voted down: Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching is now part of the core distribution of Orchard. You should really upgrade: 1.3 is very old.

Comment: But:

A) According to [this page](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Caching) Contrib.Cache is one of the ways to apply caching (and it even says _Not a single Orchard website should go into production without this module._), so is this document not updated?

B) Business-wise I don't have the option right now to upgrade to recent version. It is not a straightforward NuGet upgrade because so many things have changed and they started backward-compatibility only in about 1.4.1

Comment: If you can't upgrade, then you're out of luck. Who is "they"?

Comment: "They" is the Orchard project team. But what about my other points?

Comment: A) no, this document is not up to date. Orchard 1.7, which is imminent, has Orchard.OutputCache, which is the core version of Contrib.Cache. The framework also has an Orchard.Caching namespace with APIs that can be used by modules to cache data. Finally, SysCache is the DB caching module that is also included in 1.7.
B) We did not start backward compatibility at 1.4.1. We have always provided an upgrade path from one version to the next, since 0.1.

Comment: That's good to know! I'll mark your answer as accepted since your comments have completed the picture for me.